# Spring 3 EJB 3.1 JPA 2

Tags: spring, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0, ejb-3.1

I am looking for a template project a tutorial of how to build Spring 3 + EJB 3.1 + JPA 2 application. Any references or advices warmly appricated.

UPDATE#1 http://twasink.net/blog/2007/01/using-spring-with-ejb-3/ still looking for more answers

Comment: I don't think it is a common thing to use both Spring and EJB

Comment: Maybe you right this is why I am looking for advice, because my application should be built on top of EJB but I would like to use Spring IoC and nice features like DAO support, also I heard that it is possible to expose EJB beans as Spring beans. I am looking for best practices and other advices...

Comment: Since it's not a common thing, you may not find "best practices", but Spring documentation may be enough (see below).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of tutorials or sample projects, but:

The general way of integrating Spring with EJB is described in the chapter [20. Enterprise JavaBeans (EJB) integration](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/ejb.html), the JPA setup will probably [use JNDI and is described here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-jpa-setup-jndi).

Comment: thanks it seems to be the most correct answer on this question